# Using typeof to define a type

Tags: angular, typescript, static-typing

I don't recognize the TypeScript syntax shown [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/979657989bab4fb93faf6a207d30760faa9bd696/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/private_export.ts#L18):

```
export var __platform_browser_private__: {
  _DomAdapter?: typeof dom_adapter.DomAdapter; DomAdapter: typeof dom_adapter.DomAdapter;
  _BrowserDomAdapter?: typeof browserDomAdapter.BrowserDomAdapter;
  BrowserDomAdapter: typeof browserDomAdapter.BrowserDomAdapter;
  getDOM: typeof dom_adapter.getDOM;
  // ... shortened 
} = {
  DomAdapter: dom_adapter.DomAdapter,
  BrowserDomAdapter: browserDomAdapter.BrowserDomAdapter,
  getDOM: dom_adapter.getDOM,
  // ... shortened 
};
```

Typically I've only used `typeof` in if statements in JS but I've never seen the use of `typeof` in TypeScript to define a type.

Is this indeed a way to define a type in TypeScript? If so, is this just another way to set the type? Is this syntax idiomatic in TypeScript, are there docs? Is there a better way that Angular should be? Why this way over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning a type with `typeof`, the type becomes the constructor. Constructors are special functions for creating and initializing objects.

```
let ctor: typeof String;
ctor = String; // Works
ctor = "Some string"; // Error

let s: string;
s = "Some string"; // Works
```

The error above is `Type '"Some string"' is not assignable to type 'StringConstructor'.`

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Constructor
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html (scroll to "Advanced Techniques").

Comment: What do you mean by type constructor? Do you know of any docs on this?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood I added a link to the constructor documentation on MDN.

Comment: What he meant was this (scroll to "advanced techniques - constructor functions): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html